# Federated Decentralized Identities Across multiple public blockchains (bitcoin, ethereum, etc) through interledger

Tags: blockchain-interoperation, interoperability

are Federated Decentralized Identities across multiple public blockchains (bitcoin, ethereum, etc) through interledger possible?

I.e., ones identity can be synced across different blockchains

This will create multiple overlays of decentralized identities thereby allowing one to consume services on different blockchains and a significant improvement in resiliency -- decentralized identities of identities.